# Firebase Auth issue: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, sdk

I have this code for registering and saving user data:

```
 @objc func finishRegistering () {
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text, isValidPassword(password) else {
            presentCustomAlert(withTitle: LocalizedString.invalidPassword.translated, message: LocalizedString.passwordRules.translated)
            return
        }
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password ) { [weak self] authResult, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let strongSelf = self, let authResult = authResult else { return }
            
            strongSelf.saveUserDetails(firstname: strongSelf.firstName, lastname: strongSelf.lastName, userID: authResult.user.uid)
            
            strongSelf.navigateToHomePage()
        }
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    // MARK: -  Saving user details to the database .
    func saveUserDetails (firstname: String , lastname: String , userID: String ) {
        let databaseReference = Database.database().reference()
        
        let userReference = databaseReference.child("users").child(userID)
        
        let userdetails = ["firstName": firstname , "lastName": lastname ]
        
        userReference.setValue(userdetails) { error, _   in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Erro saving user details " , error )
                
            } else {
                print("User details saved successfully")
            }
            
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000d8d9b0 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000dbfde0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 220, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
    code = 400;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND";
            reason = invalid;
        }
    );
    message = "CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND";
}}}}
```

I tried updating firebase iOS sdk to latest version , downloaded new google plist and added that , tried cleaning build folder and packages and nothing works. How i can fix this error

Comment: I figured out the problem . I did not add authentication on the firebase app console here https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers?pli=1